# how to make dijit vertical toolbar with dojo programatically or declaratively

Tags: dojo

using dijit/Toolbar always renders horizontal toolbars. I need it to be vertical.

```
<div id="toolbar1" data-dojo-type="dijit/Toolbar"
><div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="toolbar1.cut"
    data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut', showLabel:false">Cut</div
><div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="toolbar1.copy"
    data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy', showLabel:false">Copy</div
><div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="toolbar1.paste"
    data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconPaste', showLabel:false">Paste</div
><!-- The following adds a line between toolbar sections
    --><span data-dojo-type="dijit/ToolbarSeparator"></span
 ><div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ToggleButton" id="toolbar1.bold"
    data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconBold', showLabel:false">Bold</div>
```

thanks

Comment: you can check the [demo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/menus/demo/simpleDeclarativeMenu.html) for vertical dojo menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo's toolbar can't really be made vertical but what you can do is create a dijit/Menu and not setting it to be hidden by default.

Something like this should work:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Menu">
   <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut'">Cut</div>
   <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy'">Copy</div>
</div>
```

If you want to do this programmatically, it also works. Just don't specify a targetNodeId and give the widget a node (or id) when creating it.

Also, you can modify the MenuItem css to look like a standard button (border radius, box shadows, etc) if you would like but most vertical menus I've seen with buttons end up using a more flattened style button.